# variadic template constructor and move constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

I have an template class with a variadic template constructor:

```
template<typename T, int nb = 1>
class MyClass
{
 /* ... some stuff here ... */

    template<typename... Ts>
    MyClass(Ts... ts)
    {
         /* ... some code ... */
    }

}
```

How do I define the move constructor

```
MyClass(MyClass&& source)
```

For non templated constructors what I usually do is : build an object `tmp` of type MyClass for which I `std::swap` every member with `*this` and then I swap every member of `source` with `*this*`.  Now `tmp`contains all the garbage `*this*` had and I just let the scope of my constructor taking care of deleting `tmp`...

But here I'm stuck and don't know how to construct my `MyClass tmp(???)` object.

Comment: Easy,  you were almost there: `MyClass(MyClass&& source) /* ... some more stuff here ... */`

Comment: What's the problem? What has the variadic constructor to do with the move constructor?

Comment: How do I build the `tmp` object? I'm not sure how many arguments I should put there... should I just call manually the appropriate constructor depending on `source`'s internal state? How do I call the constructor to build tmp, how many arguments, of which type?

Comment: @MCF: Why do you want to build a `tmp` object? Why do you need to do this complex dance inside your move constructor at all? What are you doing inside `MyClass` that makes `= default`ing your move constructor not possible?

Comment: For every data member, simply move the contents from the source and if you can't then copy from source. Normally the default move constructors is sufficient. If you need to instantiate a full temporary object of your class then there is no point in having a move constructor.

Comment: If the class contains (smart) pointers, building a new object is not very expensive, and if something goes wrong during the move, having put stuff in the tmp object prevents losing everything (`*this` and `source`), no?

Comment: no.. :)   instantiating smart pointers is very expensive because there is a heap allocation. Besides, I think you may be missing the point of move constructors which should be stealing memory from an rvalue rather than allocating new memory.

Comment: my mistake, I was confused between move constructor and move operator= which is where one apparently need to build the tmp and swap... (not sure why now...) http://www.codingstandard.com/rule/12-5-6-use-an-atomic-non-throwing-swap-operation-to-implement-the-copy-and-move-assignment-operators/

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the argument `Ts&&...` can match a `MyClass<T,nb>&` (i.e. non-const). This makes it a better match in the case of `auto b = a;` and similar (because a is not const).

So you'll either have to disable that case with some SFNAE magic or provide a specific overload that does the right thing:

```
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T, int nb = 1>
class MyClass
{
    /* ... some stuff here ... */

public:
    template<typename... Ts>
    MyClass(Ts&&... ts)
    : _pstr(std::make_shared<std::string>(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...))
    {
    }

    // match the specific case, and force a copy
    MyClass(MyClass<T, nb>& r)
    : MyClass(static_cast<const MyClass<T, nb>&>(r))
    {}

    // and now we must match all copy/move operations        
    MyClass(const MyClass<T, nb>&) = default;
    MyClass& operator=(const MyClass<T, nb>&) = default;
    MyClass(MyClass<T, nb>&&) = default;
    MyClass& operator=(MyClass<T, nb>&&) = default;

    void print() const {
        std::cout << *_pstr << std::endl;
    }
private:
    std::shared_ptr<std::string> _pstr;

};

// test
int main()
{
    auto a = MyClass<int>("hello, world");
    auto b = a;
    auto c = MyClass<int>("goodbye");
    auto d = c;
    b = c;
    a.print();
    b.print();
    c.print();
    d.print();
}
```

expected output:

```
hello, world
goodbye
goodbye
goodbye
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the C++17 [`in_place_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/in_place) tag type to disambiguate your constructor taking variadic arguments. Then there is no need to explicitly define the copy/move constructors like in Richard's answer.

```cpp
template<typename T, int nb = 1>
class MyClass
{
 /* ... some stuff here ... */

    template<typename... Ts>
    MyClass(std::in_place_t, Ts... ts)
    {
         /* ... some code ... */
    }

}

int main()
{
    MyClass foo(std::in_place, 123, 456);
    MyClass bar(foo);
}
```

If you don't have C++17, you can easily define your own `in_place_t` tag type as an empty struct (but not within the `std` namespace).